# POST http://localhost:8000/admin/add-users/ 404 (Not Found)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, ajax

Estoy haciendo un panel de control para administradores en mi página web con Laravel, MySQL y AJAX. Todo está funcionando bien excepto este error. No sé por qué recibo este error cuando intento acceder a mi ruta add_user.

Tengo esto en mi ruta en web.php

```
Route::post("/admin/add-users/", [App\Http\Controllers\AdminController::class, 'add_users'])->name('add_users');
```

El código del controlador es:

```
    function add_users(Request $request)
{
$data = [$request->name, $request->username, $request->email, $request->password];
$hashed_password = Hash::make($data[3]);
$adduser = DB::insert('insert into users (name, username, email, password) values (?, ?, ?, ?)', [$data[0], $data[1], $data[2], $hashed_password]);
echo $adduser;
}
```

y esta es mi solicitud AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/admin/add-users/",
    method: "POST",
    data: {
    name: name,
    username: username,
    email: email,
    password: password,
    _token: token
        },
        success: function (res) {
            if (res) {
                console.log(res);
                $('#edit-user').modal('hide');
                toastr.info('El registro fue creado correctamente',
                    'Actualizar Registro', {
                        timeout: 3000
                    });

                    $('#users_table').DataTable().ajax.reload();
                    


            } else {
                toastr.warning('Ha habido un error al crear el registro', 'Crear Registro', {
                    timeout: 3000
                });
            }
        }
    })
```

Gracias de antemano por vuestra atención

Comment: ¿Dónde te muestra el error?¿Podrías mostrar el mensaje completo? Lo más probable es que sea por la barra inclinada que pones al final de la url en `$.ajax({ url: "/admin/add-users/", ...`

Comment: Buenas, gracias por tu ayuda. No me ha funcionado quitar la barra que me has contado. El error aparece cuando hago click en un boton, el cual quiero que ejecute la funcion adduser. El mensaje del error es este:                           POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/add-users/ 404 (Not Found)
send @ jquery.js:9664
ajax @ jquery.js:9215
(anonymous) @ control-panel:406
dispatch @ jquery.js:4670
r.handle @ jquery.js:4338

Comment: Prueba quitándolo de la ruta de laravel también `Route::post("/admin/add-users/", ...`. ¿Qué información obtienes para esa ruta si haces `php artisan route:list`?

Comment: Ya lo he probado tambien y nada. Respecto al comando, lo he ejecutado y no me aparece la ruta add_users, ¿que raro no?

Comment: Entonces posiblemente las rutas estén cacheadas. Corre `php artisan route:clear` y luego otra vez `php artisan route:list`

Comment: Perfecto, ya funciona. Muchísimas gracias!